Outlook Redemption - How to modify autocomplete list on outlook 2016 and up
I am working on an issue where a client is changing their domain name for all of their email accounts. I would like to modify all the auto complete records for all of the companies outlook accounts with a console app that I can run once for each user.

I am currently working on a proof of concept with outlook 2016 and up, using Redemption to access the NickNames RDONickNames collection from the RDOSession object. When I add a record and save it does nothing. I have also tried using RDOExchangeMailboxStore RDOExchangeMailBoxStore and had no luck. It appears like it's updating the .NK2 file but not the store. It was my understanding the NK2 file is no longer being used by outlook 2016+. I have a feeling I'm misunderstanding how this part of outlook works.
My question is, how can I achieve the goal of being able to run a console app for each user to modify their auto complete records in outlook?
Here are some examples I've tried:
1.
using Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Security.Principal;
using Redemption;

var app = new Outlook.Application();
var nsp = app.GetNamespace("MAPI");
nsp.Logon();


RDOSession session = app.CreateObject("Redemption.RDOSession") as RDOSession;
session.MAPIOBJECT = nsp.MAPIOBJECT;
RDONicknames nicknames = session.GetNicknames();
nicknames.Add("The big Test <test@dimastr.com>");

nicknames.Save();




using Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Security.Principal;
using Redemption;

var app = new Outlook.Application();
var nsp = app.GetNamespace("MAPI");
nsp.Logon();


RDOSession session = app.CreateObject("Redemption.RDOSession") as RDOSession;
session.MAPIOBJECT = nsp.MAPIOBJECT;
if(session.Stores.DefaultStore is RDOExchangeMailboxStore store)
{
    var nns = store.GetNicknames();
    nns.Add("The big Test <test@dimastr.com>");
    nns.Save();
}


If you try to enumerate existing nicknames using RDONicknames, does the list match what you see in Outlook?

@DmitryStreblechenko No. When I did that the list is similar but any of my added entries do not show up when I'm trying to create a new email. The NK2 file is being changed but the outlook data store is not. My guess is outlook is not pulling from the same list at all and rather pulling from a different list somewhere else.

But if a nickname gets added by Outlook itself, the new entry is visible in Redemption, right? It is just the new entries added through Redemption are not, right?

@DmitryStreblechenko Neither are showing up. When I send an email to a new email address and it starts to auto complete in outlook. That record is not showing up in the NickNames collection. I'm also missing a lot of other records I can see in outlook but not in the collection.
